# Passing Column Name As Parameters In Prepared Statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

Using PHP and MySQLi, Can I also pass the name of the column (field) as parameter?
for example in following example I would like to list all users which they column `admin` has flagged by `1`

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `suser-tbl` WHERE ?=1 AND udepartment =?";
```

As you can see I used the first `?` placeholder in the position of the column name.

Comment: Why don't you just do `WHERE admin = 1`? You haven't explained any reason to make that a parameter.

Comment: you can't do this `WHERE ?=1` - `col=?` yes but not `?=1` - checking for errors would have spotted that. so, you can't bind tables/columns; period. Use a safelist if you want to do that.